# Moving average and moving quarterly data

Tags: r, moving-average

I have a daily time series data and wish to construct a daily moving average and create a quarterly data frame. As an example the first data set (of the example data) should include daily data for the months January, February and March, while the second series should be February, March and April. Similarly, the last data set should be that of October, November and December.   I wish to do this for the variables “tmpd, pm10median and so2median” in the sample data. How can I achieve this?

```
library(gamair) 
data(chicago) 
chicago$date<-seq(from=as.Date("1987-01-01"), to=as.Date("2000-12-31"),length=5114)
data<- chicago[,c("date","tmpd", "pm10median", "so2median" )]
```

Comment: Well, to be honest nothing useful to solve the issue. I have tried to create moving average, with this:                             library(zoo)
data$rollmean <- rollmean(data$tmpd, 2, fill = NA).  But that is not my main concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `xts` package  , you can do something like this

```
library(xts)
dat.ts <- xts(x=data[,-1],                   ## create an xts object 
              order.by=as.Date(data[,1]))    ## coerce the index to date
dat.quart <- apply.quarterly(dat.ts,mean)    ## apply for each quarter
```

To show some rows:

```
 rbind(head(dat.quart),tail(dat.quart))
               tmpd pm10median  so2median
1987-03-31 33.60556         NA         NA
1987-06-30 62.19231         NA -0.3283393
1987-09-30 71.31522         NA -1.9137842
1987-12-31 41.09783         NA         NA
1988-03-31 27.06593         NA         NA
1988-06-30 60.48352         NA         NA
1999-09-30 71.01087   2.697414 -0.4532943
1999-12-31 42.86957   1.565251 -0.4035715
2000-03-31 34.74725  -4.704813  0.2392453
2000-06-30 59.07692         NA -0.5426823
2000-09-30 69.67391         NA -1.9221470
2000-12-31 36.59783         NA -0.2387025
```

UPDATE

It looks that the OP wants to split the Moving average series by quarter.

```
dat.ts <- xts(x=data[,-1],                   ## create an xts object 
              order.by=as.Date(data[,1]))    ## coerce the index to date
dat.m <- rollmean(dat.ts,k=2)                ## compute the MA
ep <- endpoints(dat.m, "quarters")           ## create an index
## this split the seriers by quarter
xx <- sapply(1:(length(ep) - 1), function(y) { 
  dat.m[(ep[y] + 1):ep[y + 1]]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But what I wish to have is running daily means for three consecutive months, not the quarterly mean. In essence I want to have 10 separate daily data for Jan-March, Feb-April, March-May etc  until Oct -December.

Comment: Just to understand, here in dat.ts(begin 1-Jan) , for Jan-March you will get how much values?

Comment: I will get 90 values (daily mean values corresponding to the three months).

Comment: @user1754610 90 values..value1= mean(...?), value2 = mean(..?)? can you develop?

Comment: As an example the new values I want to get for tmpd  for the first for  days 1 to 5 are: NA  32.25, 33.00,  31.00  30.50, 36.00, 36.00,37.25. This results from the running average of 2 consecutive days of tmpd.

Comment: I have managed to find a solution by sub-setting in a very crude and ugly way like this (after creating running average for the entire data set):
df$month<-as.numeric(format(df$date,"%m"))  # Create month          jfm <- subset(df, df$month %in% c(1:3) )  ## Data for January to March
fma <- subset(df, df$month %in% c(2:4) )  ## Data for February to April and so on...

Comment: @user1754610 I update my answer. Hope I understood your need.